# Apple Pencil for iPad mini4

Tags: ipad, apple-pencil

I am having iPad mini 4. Does any Apple Pencil working with it ? If not then which is best alternative of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately none of the Apple Pencil products support the iPad Mini 4. You'll need the newer 5th generation iPad Mini for Apple Pencil support.

A good alternative could be the Adonit Jot Pro.